# Annoying grey block in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am working in vs when i am editing code sometimes the cursor turns into a annoying grey block which basically makes it very hard to edit anything how would i get rid of this nuisance?

the grey block:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiSBR.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have "Insert" enabled on your keyboard. Just hit the "Insert" button and it should turn off.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply it worked!

Comment: @funTertain, No problem! Glad I could help!